# What's the big-O notation for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, pseudocode

I'm currently trying to understand dynamic programming, and I found an interesting problem : "Given a chess board of nxn squares and a starting position(xs,ys), find the shortest (as in no. of moves) path a knight can take to an end position(xe,ye)". This is how my solution would sound like :

```
Initialize the matrix representing the chess board (except the "square" xs,ys) with infinity.
The first value in a queue is the square xs,ys.
while(the queue is not empty){
         all the squares available from the first square of the queue (respecting the rules of chess) get "refreshed"
         if (i modified the distance value for a "square")
                    add the recently modified square to the queue
}
```

Can someone please help me find out what's the computing-time O value for this function? I (kind of) understand big-O, but I just can't put a value for this particular function.

Comment: I don't see how this works.  "all the squares available from the first square" only applies to the first iteration.  What do you do on the second iteration - arbitrarily choose 1 square from your queue from which to recompute distances, or use a branching data structure to separately branch out and measure distances from each square in the queue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself well, I meant the first square of the queue (as in a regular queue)

Comment: Are you missing logic about not "refreshing" squares with a lower value than the current value?

Comment: I don't know what "missing logic" means. (I guess it's programmer talk :D )  If you have a square, let's call it A, and another square (B) that would be on the same distance from the starting point as A if you would represent the board as a graph. If you modify the distance of a square available from A, then do whatever, and if you modify A's distance (using a path that contains B), then the distance of the node that you "refreshed" from A is no longer optimal (you have a new , smaller, value for the distace to A)

Comment: Is this by chance a homework question?

Comment: No, I study algorithms on my own and it's just a problem i've stumbled on.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a queue, the order that you process the squares is going to be in order of minimum distance.  This means that you will only ever modify the distance value for a square once, and therefore the time will be O(n^2), since there are n^2 squares.

Comment: I thought that I will modify a square only once(I initially wanted just to check if the queue contains n^2 entities, in a static allocated queue it's really time-effective) but then I made some examples on paper and found out that you don't get the general optimal value, because there are times when the small-scale "optimal" value isn't optimal, so when you add them up, you don't get the general optimal,as well.

Comment: The first item in your queue will be the starting position, with a distance of zero.  Then you will add all the positions with a distance of one.  You will process each of these, and at the end you will have added all the positions with a distance of two, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is worded poorly

You don't define the contents of your "queue"

you don't define "refreshed"

you're always stuck on the first square, you're not keeping track of a current square.

<strike>also, Google Djkistra's algorithm</strike>  No, don't do dijkstra's algorithm.  you don't have a weighted graph.

If you want to use a dynamic programming algorithm to brute force your way to an answer, I'd start at (xe,ye), and you should be able to get O(n^2) on a nxn grid

but if you consider your constraints(your piece moves like a knight, and he moves along a  grid, and not an arbitrary graph)  you should be able to do this problem in O(n) time

Comment: The list contains information on squares (x,y coordinates), refresh means selecting the minimum value from the two options I have.   I'm familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm, but this problem is on the Dynamic programming chapter in a problem book. And also, to be honest, Dijkstra would be simpler, but I think it's good practice to not turn the action of solving problems into an algorithm. It helps you not get rooted in a certain mindset.

Comment: First of all, dynamic programming does not mean you brute-force your way to an answer. 2^n is brute-force, n^2 is a mild breeze. Second of all, D.P. implies that you calculate the local optimal solution, and use it further, until you get a general optimal solution. So I would have to pass through all the squares, so you literally can't get a solution (using DP) more efficient than O(n^2). And if I would use graphs I could just make a graph in which the adjacency of a node with another one means you can move to that square, and I could just BF from start to finish and output the cost.

Comment: You're thinking about this problem as thought it were an abstract graph problem, and not your specific chess problem, and as a chess player, I can guarantee you that if your euclidian distance between your current and target spaces is greater than some constant, than your shortest path does not include squares which are behind you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds somewhat like Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. In which case it is O(N^2), you're finding the "distance" for all possible paths from source to destination in order to determine the lowest one.

Comment: It can be thought of like Dijkstra, but that has O(n^2), hence my interest in the algorithm's complexity (even though it's impossible to be less than n^2...).

Answer (score 0):

This is a breadth first search in my opinion. It is clear that you add a square at most once in the queue and the processing of a queue entry is O(1), so the total complexity is bounded by O(N^2). However, if you can prove a theorem that tells the number of moves to get from position A to B on a NxN chess board is less than N (and intuitively this sounds reasonable for N equals or greater than 8), then your algorithm will be O(N).

Comment: Can you please detail how proving what you said would lower my O() to n?

Comment: Well, I was wrong, even if such a theorem can be proved, your initial algorithm has worst case complexity O(N^2). There might be a situation where the target position is the last one that is added to the queue, so you will check in the end all the squares of the table.

Comment: The best I can think of at this moment is a greedy heuristic where you choose the next move to be the closest (using Manhattan distance) to the target position until the distance is bellow 3. Then you run a local search to get to the target position. This will not guarantee to give you the shortest path, but it will be an O(N) time and length.